# Java8: How to get the internal Type of java.util.Optional class?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an object of type: `Optional<String>` and I would like to know at runtime what is the generic type of `Optional` - meaning 'String'.

I've tried:

```
obj.getClass()
```

but this returns `java.util.Optional`

then I tried,

```
obj.getParameterizedType();
```

but this doesn't return it has Class<> object.

Any idea??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out if what you have is just the instance of the Optional object then you're out of luck.
If, however, you have the class of the object defining the Optional property you can do something like this:

```
Class clazz = (Class) ((ParameterizedType) MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("name-of-optional-field").getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

It's butt-ugly but it works.

Answer (score 8):

There's no such thing as an object of type `Optional<String>`. Type erasure means that there's *just* `Optional` at execution time. If you have a field or parameter of type `Optional<String>`, *that* information can be retrieved at execution time - but the object itself doesn't know about it.

Basically, there's nothing special about `Optional<>` here - it has all the same limitations as using `List<>`... although as it's final, you can't even use any of the workarounds used by things like Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html).

See the [Java Generics FAQ on Type Erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Erasure) for more details.

Comment: Can you give a little example of how to retrieve it at execution time?

Comment: @Shvalb: I've just said that it *can't* be retrieved at execution time, for an object. If you mean for a *field*, I suggest you try it for yourself (and look for similar questions if necessary), and update your question if you run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the answer by Jon Skeet, you can't simply retrieve the generic type. One workaround might be something like this:

```
Class<?> type = null;
if(optional.isPresent()) {
    type = optional.get().getClass();
}
```

Of course, this won't help when the Optional is empty but for some situations it can work.